# X11 crashes when dragging a Chrome window using a touchscreen

Tags: 20.04, xorg, google-chrome, touchscreen

I connect my computer with a touchscreen. I can use it to drag windows to change their positions, but this cannot be done for Chrome windows. As long as I drag a Chrome window, the Xserver just crashes and restarts.

- Part of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[   928.141] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   928.141] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[   928.161] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Input/output error
[   928.161] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Input/output error
[   928.161] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Input/output error
[   928.163] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8
- Windowing System: X11
- Chrome Version: 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build)
- Touchscreen: Smartisan TNT go